# When The Validation Fails I Get (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs) Error Message, Why?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class named `Project` :

```
class Project { 
        static hasMany = [ tasks : Tasks , users : User ] 
        static belongsTo = User 
        String name 
        static constraints = { 
                name(nullable:false,unique:true, size:5..20) 
                tasks(nullable:true) 
                users(nullable:true) 
        } 
        String toString() { 
                this.name 
        } 
}
```

I use the following code to save the `Project` instances:

```
def save() { 
        def user = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id) 
        def projectInstance = new Project(params) 
        projectInstance.addToUsers(user) 
        if (!projectInstance.save(flush: true)) { 
            render(view: "create", model: [projectInstance: projectInstance]) 
            return 
        } 
      flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'project.label', default: 'Project'), projectInstance.id]) 
        redirect(action: "showCreatedProject", id: projectInstance.id) 
    }
```

The above code works fine if I give a `Project` `name`, which passes the domain class validation. But if I give something like `fail` as `Project` `name` (which fails the domain class validation) I get an error like this :

```
Message: null id in mnm.schedule.Project entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs) 
Trace:   Line | Method 
->> 886 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   908 | run     in     '' 
^   662 | run . . in java.lang.Thread
```

I'm very new to Grails, I don't know why this error occurs. How I can get rid of this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you remove the explicit flush call, do you still get the exception? So save() instead of save(flush:true) ?

Comment: @Gregg : Ya I have tried it, and it causes the same error. But I found that the problem is with this `projectInstance.addToUsers(user)`  line. When I comment out this line everything works fine. But I don't know how to keep that line and still escape from that error!

Comment: addToUsers() needs already saved object, seems that it needs filled ID for this object to make relations. can you try to call this method after .save()?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov : Your right. That was the mistake. Why can't you give it as a answer and I will accept it ;) ?

Comment: It was just idea because i've never tried to make `addTo` before `save` :) i've added it as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`addToUsers()` needs already saved object, because it needs filled ID to make relations. You should call this method after `.save()`

Comment: While I'm glad this fixed your problem, I'm not sure the answer is 100% accurate.  I have code that takes an unsaved object and adds other unsaved objects, and then hibernate takes care of persisting it the right way.  I think in your case, the issue is specifically because you adding a persisted object to a collection of an un-persisted object.

Comment: Seems that grails also tries to save it, before adding, but fails on validation, so he doesn't have valid id at this moment

Comment: addTo* saves the association passed as an argument because the cascading is setup in this way if you use "static belongsTo ..."
the first lines of the docs make it clear: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html